# VBA script to create folders and move files with certain criteria to those folders

Tags: vba, excel

A client has an XLSX file that contains two columns.  First columns lists the sub-folders that need to be created, the 2nd column lists Customer Numbers for PDF files that that start with the Customer Number:

example: https://imgur.com/a/J5VrorN

I need help with a script to create sub-folders for entries in column 1 under the folder specified in cell A1, then move all the PDF files that begin with the same 16 character number in column 2

(ie: `4573415225783909_01-13-2018_monthly_statement.PDF`, `4573415225783909_01-14-2018_monthly_statement.PDF`) to the newly created sub-folder the folder related to the file.

Summary: Create folder ABC23913, move any files that start with 4573415225783909 to that folder.

I figured out the create sub-folders macro:

```
Sub CreateDirs()

    Dim R As Range

    For Each R In Range("A2:A1000")
        If Len(R.Text) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & Range("A1") & "\" & R.Text & Chr(34))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next R 

End Sub
```

I'm have a hell of a time with the 2nd part. I found this online which is close, but does not move the file unless the entire file name is in the column and does not move it automatically.

```
Sub movefiles()

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "Brad", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value

        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
            Kill xSPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I can feel that I am close, but I don't know enough about VBA to have it find and move the files correctly.

A warm cookie to anyone that can help me with this mess.

Answer (score 0):

you can do every thing in one function

```
Sub Create()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DefaultPath As String
Dim NewFolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim pdfFiles As String
Dim Fobj As Object
Dim NumOfItems As Long

Set Fobj = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")

DefaultPath = "C:\"


With ws
    NumOfItems = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Item In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(NumOfItems, 1))
        NewFolderPath = DefaultPath & Item.Value
        If Fobj.folderexists(NewFolderPath) = False Then
            MkDir (NewFolderPath)
        End If

        pdfFiles = Dir(DefaultPath & "*.pdf")

        Do While pdfFiles <> ""
            If InStr(1, pdfFiles, .Cells(Item.Row, 2)) > 0 Then
                FileName = pdfFiles

                Fobj.MoveFile Source:=DefaultPath & FileName, Destination:=NewFolderPath & "\" & FileName
            End If
            pdfFiles = Dir
        Loop
    Next Item

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist Ryeo

I am getting an error:

Compile Error:
Argument not optional

And it is pointing to the first line.  Please advise.

Comment: Hi Brad E, you might need to enable scripting runtime in your reference. On error is the CreateObject highlighted?

Comment: Ryeo,
I'm sorry, i did some more digging and I got it to work.  I had to change the sheet name and the file path.  I'm working!  Thank you so much!